# Detect a movement by the camera

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if it's possible to detect a movement by the camera. The application will run on 2 phones 1 at x point and the other on x+meters and it will be used as an accurate stopper.

So the kind of movement I would like to detect is of an object passing the camera on high speed(Maximum 40 KMH).

So once again, is it possible?

Comment: It's software, just about anything is possible.  Do you have a specific question or are you just asking about computer vision in general?

Comment: I tagged android since it would be an android application, my question is it possible to detect a fast movement passing by the camera on an android camera, if yes how?

Comment: I should change my question to, how to do it instead of is it possible since the android camera detect many things such as faces and so on. so instead of detecting a face I just want to detect a moving object(btw it even detecting moving faces in my android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by comparing two images. You essentially have to override an onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) method and convert from the default YUV to RGB:

```
int[] rgb = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRGB(data, width, height);
```

Create an object which you'll use for motion detection code:

```
IMotionDetection detector = new RgbMotionDetection();
```

Call the detect() method passing in the parameters obtained above.

```
boolean detected = detector.detect(rgb, width, height)
```

If the boolean "detected" variable is true then it has detected motion.

The RGB detection code is located in RgbMotionDetection.java class. The image processing code is located in ImageProcessing.java static class. The Activity to tie it all together is in MotionDetectionActivity.java.